# A/C Air Recirculation

Tags: electrical, ac, hvac, air

In my 2017 Toyota 4Runner I'm interested in a solution to keep recirculation on by pushing a button even when the defrosters are on. In other words, a wire to override the defrosters so recirculation can be on in any mode. I thought about closing the diverter and disconnecting power to that air inlet servo however I prefer an electrical solution instead of a mechanical one. The A/C amplifier seems to use communication signals to the ECU via the CANbus system which may complicate the solution. From youtube I heard you can hold the recirculation button down for 5 seconds to keep it on however this has to be done everytime I turn on/off the car plus won't work when defrosters are on. I added a couple pics of the air inlet servo. Again I want recirculation on at all times; no "fresh air" or "outside air." Please let me know if you have any questions.

Here's a couple websites to help.

https://automotrizenvideo.com/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-file-uploads/admin/2013/10/air_conditioning-1.pdf

http://www.autocats.ws/manual/toyota/tlc200/rm.htm

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You say you want the recirc on permanently, but want an electrical solution - much easier to go mechanical with the solution you suggested...

Comment: @SolarMike The problem is, recirculation shouldn't be keeped on for too long. That's why, whenever the flap is remotely actuated, it stays on for some time and then automatically turns off.

Comment: @Al_ This comment does not agree with the last part of your post where you specifically state that "I want recirculation on at all times; no "fresh air" or "outiside air."

Comment: @SolarMike For some reason i think you're referring to me as the OP, but, if i'm right, i'm not the OP.

Comment: @Al_ sincere apologies from me - and you are also correct the recirc function is time limited - as I know from my own car.... It is to stop humidity build-up inside the car as far as I can work out.

Comment: I was referring to the OP myself. He/she should know that permanent recirculation isn't healthy and anything that isn't good for your health, when driving, can be very dangerous. Yes, you're right by the way. The mechanical solution, in the end, is the best one. In fact my car has mechanical recirculation control and can be also put at half recirculation. Just place the lever on the dashboard in the middle position. Not written on the manual, learned by myself after removing the glovebox.