# How to keep air recirculation on permanently

Tags: toyota, hvac, rav4, vents, air

I am looking to find a way to have the recirculation always in the ON position for my 2018 Toyota Rav4 Hybrid Limited.

I understand it's unhealthy to leave the same air in your car but I don't commute that far and the alternative for me is far worse. The reason I need to keep recirc on is because I have developed a severe sensitivity to fumes, especially from diesel exhaust. It causes me to get weakness and tremors in my legs and arms, dizziness, blurred vision, migraine, and if exposed too long, I will get violently sick. Even brief exposure causes symptoms. I can sense when the recirc has automatically shut off because I will get a tingling in my tongue and my legs will start to feel weak first.

I have to drive on the highway to work and it's a major truck corridor. I used to have a Toyota Sienna and I could get by with just using the defrost with foot option to keep recirc on, but that does not work with the Rav4 to keep the windshield clear. I saw the mechanical solution here: [A/C Air Recirculation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/55901/a-c-air-recirculation) , but would like to see if anyone could suggest an electrical one.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I would suggest a quality carbon filter to the incoming air....

Comment: @SolarMike Do you think that would eliminate the fumes entirely? Or would it only filter out some? If so, it wouldn't be worth spending the money. I react to the littlest bit of fumes :(

Comment: Then you probably need to be in a sealed room not in a car...